# Unable to manually symbolise iOS crash log despite having dSYMs

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode7, dsym

I was unable to get Xcode 7 to symbolise a crash log I was sent in by an App Store user, and when trying to manually symbolise it it fails, despite me having all the required dSYMs.

Crash log excerpt:

```
Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) 
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000100fa990c 
Triggered by Thread: 0

Filtered syslog: 
None found

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 
Thread 0 Crashed: 
0 libswiftCore.dylib 0x0000000100fa990c 0x100e64000 + 1333516 
1 libswiftCore.dylib 0x0000000100fa990c 0x100e64000 + 1333516 
2 MyApp 0x00000001002cdc50 0x1000a4000 + 2268240 

...

Binary Images: 
0x1000a4000 - 0x10079ffff MyApp arm64 <29a862b975b335ae91c2615c775e064f> /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CC9E1FB1-22BB-4723-B28A-95EBE21522A1/MyApp.app/MyApp
```

My app has Bitcode enabled so I downloaded the dSYMs from Xcode > Organiser > Archives. I then confirmed that `29A862B9-75B3-35AE-91C2-615C775E064F.dSYM` did indeed exist within the archive for the build that was submitted to the App Store (same build as the user was running when they had the crash).

To then manually symbolise the crash log, I ran the following in terminal:

```
$ export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
$ /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v ~/Desktop/CrashOnLaunchLogFromUser.crash  > ~/Desktop/Symbolicated.crash
```

I then waited for the processing to finish, but the resulting symbolicated file did not have the symbols replaced. When looking at the output, I saw the following information when related to my app’s binary:

```
Symbolicating...

....fetching symbol file for MyApp--[undef]
Searching []...-- NO MATCH
Searching in Spotlight for dsym with UUID of 29a862b975b335ae91c2615c775e064f
Running mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == 29A862B9-75B3-35AE-91C2-615C775E064F"
Running mdls -name com_apple_xcode_dsym_paths ...

... Lots of paths including those to all dSYMs from the correct archive that spotlight found
... I can also see that it finds the correct MyApp.app file from the archive as well

## /Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-byivrddxclcridbtblvodrqymqwv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp doesn't contain arm64 slice
UUID of executable is: 29a862b975b335ae91c2615c775e064f
Executable name: /Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-byivrddxclcridbtblvodrqymqwv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp

UUID doesn't match dsym for executable /Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-byivrddxclcridbtblvodrqymqwv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/MyApp
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo -info '/Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-byivrddxclcridbtblvodrqymqwv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp'
## /Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-byivrddxclcridbtblvodrqymqwv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp doesn't contain arm64 slice
UUID of executable is: 29a862b975b335ae91c2615c775e064f
Executable name: /Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-byivrddxclcridbtblvodrqymqwv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp

UUID doesn't match dsym for executable /Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-byivrddxclcridbtblvodrqymqwv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo -info '/Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-01/MyApp 030100.03.9 01-01-2016, 20.27.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp'
Running /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool -arch arm64 -l '/Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-01/MyApp 030100.03.9 01-01-2016, 20.27.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp'
Given UUID 29a862b975b335ae91c2615c775e064f for '/Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-01/MyApp 030100.03.9 01-01-2016, 20.27.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp' is really UUID 0209e38b2511300f967d01738731d7dd
UUID of executable is: 29a862b975b335ae91c2615c775e064f
Executable name: /Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-01/MyApp 030100.03.9 01-01-2016, 20.27.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp

UUID doesn't match dsym for executable /Users/Sencha/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2016-01-01/MyApp 030100.03.9 01-01-2016, 20.27.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp
Did not find executable for dsym
## Warning: Can't find any unstripped binary that matches version of /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/CC9E1FB1-22BB-4723-B28A-95EBE21522A1/MyApp.app/MyApp 

...

done.
0 binary images were found.
```

This all results in no symbols being replaced. Any ideas why this isn't working? All the UUIDs look okay, it finds the correct app file, dSYMs, etc. I'm happy to provide more info if required.